# OSX capture Keyboard input

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, keyboard

I write a c++ with objext-cpp application that Captur Keyboard input. 
When i Debug the application  on the xcode it worked excellent.

When I run the application no root user it only capture control keys events. 
When I run the application as root it worked excellent.

The code that create the event:

```
bool KeyboardListener::Run()
{
    bool bRet = true;

    CFMachPortRef      l_EventTap;
    CGEventMask        l_EventMask = 0;
    CFRunLoopSourceRef l_RunLoopSource = NULL;


    try
    {
        do 
        {

            l_EventMask = (CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventFlagsChanged) | CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventKeyDown));

            l_EventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGHIDEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionListenOnly , l_EventMask, KeyboardListenerEventCallback , this);

            if (l_EventTap == NULL) 
            {
                printf("failed to create event tap\r\n");
                bRet = false;
                break;
            }

            l_RunLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, l_EventTap, 0);
            CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), l_RunLoopSource , kCFRunLoopCommonModes);

            CGEventTapEnable(l_EventTap, true);

            if(l_EventTap != NULL)
            {
                CFRelease(l_EventTap);
                l_EventTap  = NULL;

            }

            if(l_RunLoopSource != NULL)
            {

                CFRelease(l_RunLoopSource);
                l_RunLoopSource = NULL;
            }


            CFRunLoopRun();


        } while (false);


        if(l_EventTap != NULL)
        {
            CFRelease(l_EventTap);

        }

        if(l_RunLoopSource != NULL)
        {

            CFRelease(l_RunLoopSource);
        }

    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        //printf("Error: Exception Occurred, System Description %s", e.what());
        bRet = false;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //printf("Error: Exception Occurred");
        bRet = false;
    }

    return bRet;
}
```

It possible to run this application as "LaunchAgents"?
 What I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance